# Generate huge image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I need to create a huge image (aprox 24000 x 22000) with PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb encoding. I know it will barely impossible to open it...

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
Bitmap final = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

As expected, an exception is thrown as I can't handle a 11GB file in memory easy that way.

But I had an idea: could I write the file as I'm generating it? So, instead of working on RAM, I would be working on the HD.

Just to better explain: I have about 13K tiles and I plan to stitch it together in this stupidly humongous file. As I can iterate them in a give order, I thing I could write it down directly to the memory using unsafe code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of unmanaged code, please read unsafe code...

Comment: See [Memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg memorymapped file _can_ be used to open/edit sections from a big file.... but its **NOT RECOMMANDED** creating those big files in memory mappedfile !!!

Comment: @RoyiNamir Nobody says you must have a window that covers the whole file. Any existing window would cover just one tile. Or one scanline.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - why do you say that?  On the contrary, memory-mapped files are the recommended way to create, manipulate, (and share between processes), huge data sets. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/salvapatuel/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4/   Of course you don't try to hold the entire file in memory at once - that is the whole point of memory-mapping the file.

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick's [Large Image Support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel) (tera-pixel) can help you put the image together once you have the tiles that compose it. You can either use use the command line and issue commands to it using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagickapp/) wrapper or use this [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) as an API.

Comment: Seems promising! I will give a look on this API! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link to ImageMagick.NET - I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it in a non-compressed format like BMP. BMP saves raw color bytes in rows. So you would load first row of tiles, read their separate pixel rows and write it as composite single row in output image. This way, you can have open only few tiles and imediately write down the output image.

But I don't know how to write it as compressed image, like JPG or PNG. But I'm sure some specialised software exists for that.

Comment: I got your idea and it is a good approach, but there is an issue: As the Bitmap class checks if the system can handle such big files, it won't let me pass from the new Bitmap().

Comment: Key point here is, that you shouldnt use any in-build classes for image manipulation. You should do it raw. So as I said, use BMP, which is extremly simple raw image format, that you can write without any complex compressing algorithm.

Comment: Hmmm... Now I got it. That's indeed a good idea! I will give a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you intend to do with this image upon completion, I would suggest dividing it into 4 and working with it that way.  I have worked with 10,000 x 10,000 pixels without the OOM exception being thrown.

Comment: Right now it is exactly what I'am doing and it is a valid workaround, but as I have no rush in creating this files, I'm studying approaches for the problem!

Comment: FWIW, I find it much safer to stay below 8192 x 8192 pixels.  Especially if holding multiple textures in memory at one time (for example, to copy from one to another).